# Is it possible to change the graphics settings in Sonic All-Stars Racing: Transformed?

Tags: sonic-all-stars-racing-transformed

The game does not have a menu to choose the graphical options.

**Is there any possibility to change the graphics in this game?**

For example in Grand Theft Auto V can be used one `commadline` to set the desired graphical option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a *launcher.exe* in the game files that opens up a configuration window that should appear with advanced options as shown:

[image: Advanced options]

The picture can be found on the [PC Gaming Wiki page](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Sonic_%26_Sega_All-Stars_Racing), along with other tweaks.